# Setting Date Parameters in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I am a beginner to MySQL and have written some basic MySQL stored procedures but cannot see what is wrong with the code below, I am getting the error

"Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 9"

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CA_Daily 
(
DateTime_Start datetime
)
BEGIN



SET DateTime_Start = DATE_FORMAT((CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY )   ,'%Y%-%m-%d %T');

END;
```

There is a lot more to the original code which when I run it just as a piece of script works fine its just when I try to create it as a stored procedure it fails, I have it down to how I am dealing with the parameters but not sure what I am doing wrong....if not everything.

Any help would be great.

Comment: DATE_FORMAT returns VARCHAR, not DATETIME.

Comment: Hi Andrey, thanks for the reply, I have tried declaring it as a varchar but am still stuck with the same error, the error shows at the end of the set statement saying I am missing a semicolon but as you can see it is there??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE CA_Daily1
(
DateTime_Start datetime
)
BEGIN
    SET DateTime_Start = DATE_FORMAT((CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY )   ,'%Y%-%m-%d %T');
END$$
```

Comment: Hi Andrey, thanks again for the response, I have run your code and it saves correctly without an error but when I call it, e.g. call CA_Daily1 it expects a parameter i.e. DateTime_Start.  What I want it to do is take what is defined within the set statement as the DateTime_Start and not require me to input a parameter, if that sort of makes sense.

Comment: Hi Andrey, I have it through your help, I needed the DELIMITER $$ then set the variables after the begin statement, put in the rest of my select and then my following END$$ and all works fine when I call it, though I am going to need to read up on the DELIMITER$$ meaning as I haven't used this before but thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the STR_TO_DATE conversion in your SET statement:

Example:

```
STR_TO_DATE('8/21/2017 12:58 PM', '%c/%e/%Y %H:%i')
```

Comment: Hi hackela, thanks for the reply, but that doesn't seem to change the error message?